# Why does the position of the IHL and the version matter in the Internet Header?

Tags: c, networking, ip, endianness

I was recently doing some raw socket related programming on my Ubuntu virtual machine. I decided to check the IP header definition in `/usr/include/netinet/ip.h` and I found this snippet of code to perplex me:

```
struct iphdr
{
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
unsigned int ihl:4;
unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
unsigned int version:4;
unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
...
```

Whenever I have examined a diagram of the IP header, however, the version and the IHL always seemed to go first. In the [original RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), this also seems to be the case. So, why is it that the order changes depending on the endianness of the machine? As far as my understanding goes, endianness is used for storing multi-byte values.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bitfields (like `ihl` and `version` here) are usually assigned either right-to-left or left-to-right within a word, depending on the endianness of the machine. (This is hideously compiler-dependent and not at all guaranteed, but it tends to work, but it's why some people recommend not using bitfields at all, although if you're not reading and writing them externally it doesn't matter so much.)

Comment: Wow, that was quite simple. Thanks!